# Put files in a subversion repository with no history/versioning?

Tags: svn

Is there any way to mark a file in a subversion repository as non-versioned?  Basically, for some files I have, mostly test output, it's really handy to have them in the repository, but they take up a lot of space and I don't need the previous versions at all.  They are easy enough to regenerate if they get lost somehow.

So, I hoped there was a property I could set to not save file history, but there doesn't seem to be any such thing, and the whole idea may be incompatible with svn.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to store large binaries in SVN repository. SVN supports storing both textual and binary data and does not have technical limits to repository size. All files are stored differentially in the repository. However, in your case I'd avoid storing those files in Subversion repository because they can be regenerated from source.

> but they take up a lot of space and I don't need the previous versions at all. They are 
>   easy enough to regenerate if they get lost somehow.

You say that these files can be easily regenerated and you don't need the change history. So do you really need to keep these files under version-control? You can [configure Subversion to ignore these files](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).

Comment: You are correct, I do not need them under version control.  It's just very handy to have them come along in a checkout.  With the test results in the repo we know  all the developers have the up-to-date test files no matter where they are working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the version control part of SVN but I agree that having these files polluting your main repository is less than ideal.

I would recommend creating a separate repository (e.g. `test-output-svn`) and then using [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) to link that repository to your main one. Then when you checkout your main repository, you'll get the test output stuff as well.

You can then also choose not to checkout the test output stuff (for build etc.) with the command:

```
svn checkout --ignore-externals http://url/to/main/repo
```